# Gamma function returns unstable value?

Tags: r, nan, gamma-function

Gamma function should not take any negative value as an argument. Look at the code below where strange thing happens. Is this some problem with R?

I was using function `optim` to optimize some function containing:

```
gamma(sum(alpha))
```

with respect to `alpha`. R returns negative `alpha`.

```
> gamma(sum(alpha))
[1] 3.753+14
>sum(alpha)
[1] -3
gamma(-3)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In gamma(-3) NaN's produced.
```

Can somebody explain? Or any suggestion for the optimization?

Thanks!

Comment: -3 is a pole, and thus gamma function as x tends to -3 will be infinity. for you to note that `sum(alpha)` is not `-3` just do simply `sum(alpha)==-3` it will give you false. Since `sum(alpha)` is technically close to -3 but is not -3, `identical(sum(alpha),-3)`

Comment: It appears that everyone now needs to  read the `?gamma` help page.

Comment: From the help: `The gamma function is defined by (Abramowitz and Stegun section 6.1.1, page 255)

Γ(x) = integral_0^Inf t^(x-1) exp(-t) dt

for all real x except zero and negative integers (when NaN is returned). `

Comment: In R -3 is not of integer type. Looks like `sum(alpha)` is near `-3L-0.0000000000000004`

Comment: Thanks! So Gamma function is defined for negative numbers expect negative integers.

Comment: Yes. We can show that `Gamma(x) = 1/x Gamma(x)`.  If `x = -3/2`, then `Gamma(-3/2) = -2/3 * Gamma(-1/2) = -2/3 * -2/1 * Gamma(1/2) = 4/3 * sqrt(pi)`. It fails for negative integers because `Gamma(0)` isn't defined. (grad school notes: http://www.suchanutter.net/ItCanBeShown/gamma-function.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gamma function is "not defined" at negative integer argument values so R returns Not a Number (`NaN`). The reason of the "strange" behaviour is decimal representation of numbers in R. In case the number differs from the nearest integer not very much, R rounds it during printing (in fact when you type `alpha`, R is calling for `print(alpha)`. Please see the examples of such a behaviour below.

```
gamma(-3)
# [1] NaN
# Warning message:
#  In gamma(-3) : NaNs produced
x <- -c(1, 2, 3) / 2 - 1e-15
x
# [1] -0.5 -1.0 -1.5
sum(x)
# [1] -3
gamma(sum(x))
# [1] 5.361428e+13
curve(gamma, xlim = c(-3.5, -2.5))
```

Please see a graph below which explains the behaviour  of gamma-function near negative integers:
[image]